# Serilog Cloudwatch logging not enriching the logs

Tags: .net-core, amazon-cloudwatch, serilog

I have used Serilog in the past and enriched logs with various properties. However I am playing around with the new AWS Lambda Serverless templates using .net core 3.1 and cannot get the logs to enrich. I have tried this in a basic Console app as well with the same result.

Example: code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.AWSSeriLog(GetAwsSerilogConfiguration())
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .CreateLogger();

        using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 1))
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }

    private static AWSLoggerConfig GetAwsSerilogConfiguration()
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        return new AWSLoggerConfig
        {
            LogGroup = $"AwsLoggingTestConsoleApp/{environmentName ?? "Development"}",
            Region = RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2.SystemName
        };
    }
}
```

The following screenshots from Cloudwatch Logs and Insights show the log generated by this code. The enriched property 'A' and MachineName do not appear

[Cloudwatch Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1DMA.jpg)

[Cloudwatch Insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a3nI.jpg)

I feel like I am missing something obvious, but for the life of me I cannot see it.

Any ideas why the logs are not being enriched?

Many thanks,

M.

Comment: what error(s) are you getting??

Comment: since you are checking  /Development, for a start, change $"AwsLoggingTestConsoleApp/{environmentName ?? "Development"}"  TO  $"AwsLoggingTestConsoleApp/Development"  So you can be sure of path it's going

Comment: else, go to the config file (appsetting.json)  and find out the value of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT, then you can set it explicitly for certainty sake. if it is say Staging then you'd have  => AwsLoggingTestConsoleApp/Staging

Comment: @Damilola thanks for your comments. I am seeing the log entry created in a new LogStream each time I execute the code. These appear in the correct LogGroup as the screenshots show. I have used a static LogGroup name as well with the same result. I'm not using an appsettings file - the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value is in my Environment Variables and is set to Development.

I am not getting any errors. Its just that the enriched values are not appearing in the logs.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I am running into the same issue. MSSqlServer Sink is enriching from LogContext fine, but not for AWSSerilog.

Comment: @Longo No I didnt. If you find one, please let me know here